# SharpSVN list of users

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

Is there any way to get list of all users who have access to a SVN project with SharpSVN?
A user may not add/edit any file, yet, but he has access to that project.

Answer (score 2):

No. Whoever has access is determined by the server and there is no way to retrieve this for any specific server. On the server side you might look in the config files to see who has access, but this could be something like 'anybody on this active directory domain'.